# GetProcAddress and Function pointers - Is this correct?

Tags: c++, dll

I am currently having a problem accessing a method in a dll file. The method that i am attempting to access is of the type.

```
int dstoch (float,float,float,float,float,float,float,float,float);
```

This is the code I am using

```
typedef int (*LPMyfunct)(float,float,float,float,float,float,float,float,float);

HINSTANCE hDLL = NULL;
LPMyfunct lpdstoch;

hDLL = LoadLibrary("c:\\myfile.dll");

if(hDLL!=NULL)
{
    std::cout << "Library loaded \n";
    lpdstoch = (LPMyfunct)GetProcAddress((HMODULE)hDLL, "dstoch");

    int res = LPMyfunct(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9); //this is where I am getting an error
}
```

The compile time error states :
`a value of type LPMyfunct cannot be used to initialize an entity of type int`

Any suggestions on why it wont accespt the 9 parameters ?

Comment: You should check for `lpdstoch` being a null pointer as well.

Comment: I definitely will do that but first I cant figure why the funct ptr wont take the 9 arguments

Comment: The answer says it all. `LPMyfunct` is a type, which can't be used like a function.

Comment: Yeah apparently for some reason the answer didnt show up when I posted this comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace `LPMyfunct` with `lpdstoch`.

Comment: @MistyD I hope you understand what was wrong with the original code and why this fixes it. Otherwise, you'll just be back here tomorrow with another question.